# Put .apk of an app module as resource of another module

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an Android Studio project with several modules.

Two of them are apps, ParentApp and ChildApp. I'd like ParentApp to contain ChildApp.apk [*].

How can I configure ParentApp's `build.gradle` so that building ParentApp.apk will also build ChildApp.apk if necessary? and automatically copy ChildApp.apk in ParentApp's `res/raw` or `assets` directory?

*: Unfortunately I can't just convert ChildApp in a library; ChildApp's code must run as a different UID and therefore it must stay in a different Android package. ParentApp already has privileges to install ChildApp.apk.